# Как постоянно показывать controls у видео?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, видео

Почему если видео запускалось с помощью .play() , то не работает .controls = true ? Причем если видео запускалось стандартной кнопкой или использовались другие стандартные элементы управления, то .controls = true начинает работать? Как это исправить?

Запускаем видео нажав на playVideo(выполняется .play()), пытаемся навести курсор на addControls(должен делать видимыми элементы управления тега video), он не работает.

Но если видео запускалось стандартной кнопкой, или нажатием на область видео, то наведение на addControls делает  элементы управления видео видимыми. Наводить на addControls нужно естественно когда видео воспроизводится и элементы управления скрылись чтобы не мешать просмотру.

```js
let myVideo = document.querySelector(".myVideo");
//управление кнопкой воспроизведения
var triangle = document.querySelector(".triangle");

function playVideo() {
  myVideo.play();
}


let addControls = document.querySelector(".addControls");
// Добавляем обработчик события mouseover для div
addControls.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  // Задаем свойство controls для видео
  myVideo.controls = true;
});
```

```html
<video class="myVideo" controls src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"> 
</video>
<div onclick="playVideo()">playVideo</div>
<div class="addControls">addControls</div>
```

Comment: Они же уже есть...

Comment: @Qwertiy Когда видео воспроизводится и курсор вне видео, или долго на одном месте, то элементы управления убираются чтобы не мешать просмотру- браузер убирает. Вот в этот момент их хотелось бы вернуть обратно при наведение на заданный div(а не обратно на видео). И, как я описал в вопросе, они возвращаются обратно если видео было запущено стандартной кнопкой, но не возвращаются(без каких-либо ошибок в консоли), если видео было запущено с помощью .play().

Comment: А если прочитать документацию, что делает присваивание video.controls = true, то не наводит на мысль, что оно показом вообще управлять не должно?

Comment: @Qwertiy Так объясни пож. что происходит по итогу? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_video_controls.asp написано устанавливает должно ли видео отображать стандартные элементы управления видео. Т.е. если оно true, то элементы должны быть видны по идее. И почему работает если видео запускалось стандартной кнопкой? Как стандартная кнопка отрабатывает в видео не понятно... Теневой dom - хз как понять как работает под капотом.

Comment: Это свойство отвечает за то, доступны ли контролы вообще пользователю. Если false, то он не сможет никак стандартно управлять видео (хотя, контекстное меню вроде бы останется), а если true, то сможет. Оно не отвечает за видимость контролов в конкретный момент на экране.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот https://jsfiddle.net/otnfccgu/2/ кто-то специально сделал моргание контролов с помощью данного свойства setInterval(function(){ myVideo.controls = !myVideo.controls; },500)  То видимые, то невидимые. И, как я уже несколько раз повторил, если видео запускалось с помощью стандартной кнопки , то video.controls = true  СДЕЛАЕТ ВИДИМЫМИ контролы.   Да и написал бы как их сделать видимыми по другому, а не пустоту эту. Стили установленные в shadow dom тоже не удалось перебить(с помощью video::-webkit-media-controls-panel), хотя например красной(background-color: red;) панель делается.

Comment: @Qwertiy И   video.controls = false, тоже отрабатывает, скрывая панель управления.  Может какая защита чтобы не управляли видео без участия пользователя - часть функций управления не вызывается ведь до определенного момента, например play() до нажатия на кнопку на странице(но там в консоли соответствующая ошибка вылезает).

Comment: jsfiddle пока открыть не могу (он не работает в России). Скорее всего, при запуске стандартной кнопкой с панели она имеет фокус, поэтому панель появляется. А при запуске твоей кнопкой фокус на ней, поэтому панель не появляется. Кстати, а это идея - поставить фокус на видео.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если видео будет в фокусе, то в моём хроме получается постоянно показывать контролы. Установку фокуса в таймер не поместил, поскольку она будет мешать нормальному взаимодействию пользователя со страницей, но если пользователь больше ничего не трогает, то установки фокуса вне таймера достаточно.

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video')

video.focus()
video.controls = true
setInterval(() => video.controls = true, 1000)
```

```css
html, body, video { height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; }
```

```html
<video controls autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Вариант с кнопкой:

```js
let timer

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const video = document.querySelector('video')

  video.play()
  video.focus()
  video.controls = true
  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setInterval(() => video.controls = true, 1000)
});
```

```css
html, body, video { height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; }
button { position: absolute; inset: 0 auto auto 0; margin: .25em; }
```

```html
<button>Play</button>

<video controls muted loop>
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Да, с фокусом все работает. Ты крут! Можно еще добавить запуск с кастомной кнопки к ответу, чтобы зашедший мог сразу убедиться,  что фокус помогает. <div onclick="playVideo()">playVideo</div>       function playVideo() {myVideo.play();}  Если это прочитает кто-то шарящий как оно там внутри и что отрабатывает, то напиши пож. в комменте почему без фокуса не работает, а с ним все OK.

Comment: @Hertz, добавил.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью css можно принудительно показать шкалу, но не кнопки.

У панели кнопок псевдоэлмент начинается с `-internal`, а не с `-webkit` - похоже, такие элементы в стилях прописывать нельзя.

```css
html, body, video { height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; }

::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  display: flex !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

::-internal-media-controls-button-panel { /* не работает */
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<video controls autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```